# django id integer limit

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-postgresql

Is there a limit to the AutoField in a Django model or the database back-ends?

The Django project I am working on could potentially see a lot of objects in certain database tables which would be in excess of 40000 within a short amount of time.

I am using Sqlite for dev and Postgresql for production.

Comment: The limit is dependent on postgresql's maximum value for an integer field

Comment: AFAIK, it is limited only by the backend database engine. In the case of postgres, I doubt you will ever reach the 2,147,483,647 limit.

Comment: @PauloScardine: And there's always `bigserial` (9 223 372 036 854 775 807) if needed.

Comment: Just an FYI - using two different database backends between local development and production may cause issues/inconsistencies etc. It "should" be fine for simple projects, but just remember you should replicate your production environment as closely as possible whilst in development. (Also, PostgreSQL backends allow for slightly different field types as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)

Answer (score 11):

Adding this as an answer.  Django maps this to serial columns which means that the maximum value is in the 2 billion range ( 2,147,483,647 to be exact).  While that is unlikely to be an issue for most applications, if you do, you could alter the type to become a bigint instead and this would make it highly unlikely you will ever reach the end of 64-bit int space.

Answer (score 11):

Adding new info for `Django 2.x`:

---

Djangos [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#autofield) is an [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.IntegerField). The docs for `IntegerField` say:

> Values from `-2.147.483.648` to `2.147.483.647` are safe in all databases supported by Django.

`AutoField` per default only uses positive numbers, so the values can go from `1` to `2.147.483.647`.

---

Since `Django 1.10` there is also an [`BigAutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield), which is very similar to the [`BigIntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#bigintegerfield).
The docs for `BigAutoField` say:

> A 64-bit integer [...] that is guaranteed to fit numbers from `1` to `9.223.372.036.854.775.807`.

Now, the docs don't say it explicitly for this field, but by using the words `is garanteed to fit`, I assume that applies for all databases supported by Django.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned whether you use `int` or `bigint`, respectively you have  `2.147.483.648` or `9.223.372.036.854.775.808` values.

If you think to exceed those numbers, you can do sharding.
In short, sharding is a way of horizontally partitioning your data by storing different rows of the same table in multiple tables across multiple databases.

There are available many sharding libraries for Django (e.g. [django-sharding](https://github.com/JBKahn/django-sharding))