# Django+PostgreSql: Can I run out of id/pk?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In my application, I am going to need a setup where every user has some derived/calculated information in the database. It should be maximum 100 different data sets with each around 100 rows (100x100) per user. These rows need to be refreshed around every three months. So, let's say with 10000 users if everybody uses all hundred places that would be 100M rows recreated every 3 months. As far as my knowledge the Postgre int field is 2147483647, that is 2100M+. So, am I going to run out of id/pk in around 5 years with this setup?

Should I rethink my setup or is there a way around?

I am using Python 2.7.6, PostgreSQL server is 9.3 and Django 1.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django id integer limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150973/django-id-integer-limit)

Comment: Django (1.10 onwards) provides the [`BigAutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield). You'd need to create subclass of the `models.Model`, overwrite the `id` field and then inherit from that.

Comment: @Kendas: Good suggestion. So, at some point in time the db really has to use ids of multiple million in value? I hoped for some auto-reindex or soemthing like that, before it gets to the crazy numbers ... :-)

Comment: @Kendas: If you want repost your comment as an answer I accept that, it provides me with more specific info on how to modify my project.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it just keeps growing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first instinct was to use the [`BigAutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield), but that does not exist in Django 1.8. In any case, you'd use it like so:

```
from django.db import models

class CustomIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

class SomeModel(CustomIDModel):
    some_field = model.BooleanField()
    # More
```

Django 1.8 does have the [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield), however. This is larger but should do the trick.

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class CustomIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class SomeModel(CustomIDModel):
    some_field = model.BooleanField()
    # More
```